# Is it possible to use a different buffer with Node Stream?

Tags: node.js

I have a class that extends Writable from Stream.

From the following link https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_streams_under_the_hood

.. I understand that this inherently uses a buffer, but I want it to use a ring buffer instead. Is it easy to implement? Or am I on the wrong path here? I'm a Node noob.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have an existing code base i need to modify. When the buffer is full subsequent additions are lost, but I want to change it so as it's FIFO

Comment: anybody have anything to add on this, no? many thanks